Ansible: How to merge a list and dict into new nested dict
I'm trying to build reverse look-up (PTR) records for bind.
I have a CSV file with IP and Hostname fields loaded into a dict (from read_csv), so I guess it's a list of dicts actually:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": false,
            "dict": {},
            "failed": false,
            "list": [
                {
                    "hostname": "host1",
                    "ip": "10.32.1.32"                                                            
                },
                {
                    "hostname": "host2",
                    "ip": "10.50.6.71"                                                            
                },
                {                                                                                     
                    "hostname": "host3",
                    "ip": "10.36.254.41"                                                          
                },
                {
                    "hostname": "host4",
                    "ip": "10.36.254.42"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}

And I have a list of unique reversed last two octets derived from the above dict:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "32.10",
            "50.10",
            "36.10"
        ],
    ]
}

What I want is a new dict that looks like (formatting might not be correct, pls forgive):
{
   "32.10": 
          {
              "hostname": "host1",
              "ip": "10.32.1.32"                                                            
          },
   "50.10":
          {
              "hostname": "host2",
              "ip": "10.50.6.71"                                                            
          },
   "36.10":
          {                                                                                     
              "hostname": "host3",
              "ip": "10.36.254.41"                                                          
          },
          {
              "hostname": "host4",
              "ip": "10.36.254.42"
          }
}

The new "super" dict should have only the IP + Hostname entries for that matched network (eg. all the 10.36.x.x entries should be under "36.10").
From this new dict, I should then be able to loop through it in a template to generate the PTR records.
I'm stumped as to how to merge these two data structures. :-/
Thank you!

Your desired data structure doesn't make sense. It looks like you intend that the value of each key should be a list of dictionaries. Please update the syntax appropriately; you can find JSON syntax documentation all over the place (e.g. here).

You can make use of the combine filter to build your final dictionary.
Something like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    results:
      - hostname: host1
        ip: 10.32.1.32
      - hostname: host2
        ip: 10.50.6.71
      - hostname: host3
        ip: 10.36.254.41
      - hostname: host4
        ip: 10.36.254.42
  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ results }}"
      vars:
        reversed: {}
        key: >-
          {{"{}.{}".format(*((item.ip.split('.'))[:2]|reverse))}}
      set_fact:
        reversed: >-
          {{
          reversed|combine({key: reversed.get(key, []) + [item]}, list_merge='append_rp')
          }}

    - debug:
        var: "reversed"

We construct the dictionary key using the following expression:
{{"{}.{}".format(*((item.ip.split('.'))[:2]|reverse))}}

That transforms something like "a.b.c.d" to "b.a". We use that + the combine filter + the list_merge option to the combine filter to get the final data structure; the above playbook produces this output:
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "reversed": {
        "32.10": [
            {
                "hostname": "host1",
                "ip": "10.32.1.32"
            }
        ],
        "36.10": [
            {
                "hostname": "host3",
                "ip": "10.36.254.41"
            },
            {
                "hostname": "host4",
                "ip": "10.36.254.42"
            }
        ],
        "50.10": [
            {
                "hostname": "host2",
                "ip": "10.50.6.71"
            }
        ]
    }
}


larsks, I owe you big time! Thank you so much! It works perfect. The only issue is that it wouldn't work with ansible v2.9.6 (Ubuntu 20.04), I had to upgrade to the latest v2.12.2 and it works great. This is exactly what I needed. Deo gratias!!


Given the keys

  keys: ['32.10', '50.10', '36.10']


Select the values

  vals: |
    {% for k in keys|map('split', '.')|map('reverse')|map('join', '.') %}
    - {{ results | selectattr('ip', 'match', k) }}
    {% endfor %}

gives
  vals: |-
    - [{'hostname': 'host1', 'ip': '10.32.1.32'}]
    - [{'hostname': 'host2', 'ip': '10.50.6.71'}]
    - [{'hostname': 'host3', 'ip': '10.36.254.41'}, {'hostname': 'host4', 'ip': '10.36.254.42'}]


Create the dictionary

  rev: "{{ dict(keys|zip(vals|from_yaml)) }}"

gives what you want
  rev:
    '32.10':
    - {hostname: host1, ip: 10.32.1.32}
    '36.10':
    - {hostname: host3, ip: 10.36.254.41}
    - {hostname: host4, ip: 10.36.254.42}
    '50.10':
    - {hostname: host2, ip: 10.50.6.71}



Notes:

Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    keys: ['32.10', '50.10', '36.10']
    results:
      - {hostname: host1, ip: 10.32.1.32}
      - {hostname: host2, ip: 10.50.6.71}
      - {hostname: host3, ip: 10.36.254.41}
      - {hostname: host4, ip: 10.36.254.42}

    vals: |
      {% for k in keys|map('split', '.')|map('reverse')|map('join', '.') %}
      - {{ results | selectattr('ip', 'match', k) }}
      {% endfor %}
    rev: "{{ dict(keys|zip(vals|from_yaml)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vals
    - debug:
        var: rev | to_yaml


Optionally, convert the lists to dictionaries

  rev: "{{ dict(keys |
                zip(vals |
                    from_yaml |
                    map('items2dict',
                        key_name='hostname',
                        value_name='ip'))) }}"

gives
  rev:
    '32.10':
      host1: 10.32.1.32
    '36.10':
      host3: 10.36.254.41
      host4: 10.36.254.42
    '50.10':
      host2: 10.50.6.71

, or
  rev: "{{ dict(keys |
                zip(vals |
                    from_yaml |
                    map('items2dict',
                        value_name='hostname',
                        key_name='ip'))) }}"

gives
  rev:
    '32.10':
      10.32.1.32: host1
    '36.10':
      10.36.254.41: host3
      10.36.254.42: host4
    '50.10':
      10.50.6.71: host2


